# PHP WordPress issue with isset() Function

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, post, isset

All this code is written on the same page

```
 <form method="post" action = "http://mypage.lhosting.info/login/" >
    <p> Username: <input type="text" name = "username" /> </p><br>
    <p> Password: <input type="text" name = "password" /></p> <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />
 </form>

 if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['submit'])) 
 {
   $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
   $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);
   $sql = "INSERT INTO Duomenys (Username, Password) VALUES ('$username','$password')"; 
 }
```

The `if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['submit']))` does not trigger, it sends the account's details to my database everytime I refresh the page. What am I doing wrong?

Note: Still learning PHP and WordPress

Comment: have you put the code of submit in <?php ?> ?

Comment: Yes @AhmedGinani

Comment: You can check actually $_POST['submit'] != '' instead of !empty

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['submit']) )` should be enough

Comment: When you *refresh* the page? Do you submit the form and then *refresh* the page? Does your browser ask you something along the lines of "Are you sure you want to refresh the page and submit the data again?"…?

Comment: Also: [Why check both isset() and !empty()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4559925/476)

Comment: Duplicate.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/359050/2870399 Better use `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/3144006/476

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$_POST['submit']` will always **set** and **not empty** it's value is already set as **Register**.

You need to check that `username` and `password` should not empty. Hence write

```
if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])){
    // querycode here
}
```